# How to mix CGLIB and JDK proxies in Spring configuration files?

Tags: java, spring, aop, cglib, proxies

This thread is related to a problem I am encountering [here regarding the needs for access to protected methods of an advised class](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10110253/827480).  I'm using Spring 3.0.6, and have created a Spring profiling aspect that I am applying to a significant number of beans using JDK proxies.

However, due to the need to access protected methods in one particular bean, I would like to advise it using CGLIB.  All other beans I would like to continue to use JDK Proxies.

I am using a mix of annotations and xml configuration, but this particular aspect is defined in XML configuration.

I know that there is `<aop:scoped-proxy>` tag, but from what I can tell, that applies to all aspects.

Is there anyway to define for a single aspect to use CGLIB instead?

```
<aop:config>
    <aop:aspect id="Profiler" ref="lendingSimulationServiceProfilerInterceptor">
        <!-- info -->
        <aop:around method="infoProfiler"
                    pointcut="execution(* com.cws.cs.lendingsimulationservice.service.LendingSimulationServiceImpl.calculate*(..))"  />

        <!-- debug -->
        <aop:around method="infoProfiler"
                    pointcut="execution(* com.cws.cs.lendingsimulationservice.process.LendingSimulationProcessImpl.calculate(..))"  />

        <aop:around method="infoProfiler"
                    pointcut="execution(* com.blaze.BlazeEngine.invokeService(..))"  />

        <!-- trace -->
        <aop:around method="traceProfiler" 
                    pointcut="execution(* com.calculator.dao.impl.LendingSimulationDaoImpl.*(..))"  />

        <!-- NEED TO DEFINE THIS PARTICULAR ASPECT AS CGLIB -->
        <aop:around method="traceProfiler" 
                    pointcut="execution(* com.cws.cs.lendingsimulationservice.util.pool.JAXBPoolImpl.*(..))"    />
    </aop:aspect>
</aop:config>
```

I've tried to split the configuration into two, and for one configuration specify `target-class="true"` and the other `target-class="false"`, but it seems to apply CGLIB to all at that point.

Is there any way to accomplish this?

Thanks,

Eric

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Unfortunately, either all or none beans use CGLIB and if you use proxying of target class in one place, it is forced in all other places. Quoting [8.6 Proxying mechanisms](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/aop.html#aop-proxying) of official documentation:

> #### Note
>
> Multiple `<aop:config/>` sections are collapsed into a single unified auto-proxy creator at runtime, which applies the strongest proxy settings that any of the `<aop:config/>` sections (typically from different XML bean definition files) specified. This also applies to the `<tx:annotation-driven/>` and `<aop:aspectj-autoproxy/>` elements.
>
> To be clear: using `'proxy-target-class="true"'` on `<tx:annotation-driven/>`, `<aop:aspectj-autoproxy/>` or `<aop:config/>` elements will force the use of CGLIB proxies *for all three of them*.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  I was afraid of that.  But then I found [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7638251/827480) which seemed to indicate that he got it working, but even if I annotate my target class (JAXBPoolImpl) with `@Scope( proxyMode = ScopedProxyMode.TARGET_CLASS )` it doesn't seem to work for me.